# Rails / RSpec: How to trigger Puffing Billy only on specific tests by using RSpec metadata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I would like to switch to `webkit_billy` (the Javascript driver of [Puffing Billy gem](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy/))  **only in certain tests**.  I want to be able to use:

```
describe "xxx", billy: true do
end
```

This should signal to RSpec that I want to switch to puffing billy driver.

I wrote this in `spec_helper.rb` but it's not working:

```
  config.before(:each) do |example|
    if [:billy].include? example.metadata[:type]
      Capybara.current_driver     = :webkit_billy
      Capybara.javascript_driver  = :webkit_billy
    else
      Capybara.current_driver     = :webkit
      Capybara.javascript_driver  = :webkit 
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybara.javascript_driver is only used (with normal configuration) when `js: true` metadata is added to the test so there is no need to keep resetting the value of javascript_driver to :webkit_billy since all that would do is affect any further tests with the `js` metadata.  You can see the default behavior implementation (when you require capybara/rspec) [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec.rb#L28) 
What this does is initially set the driver for the test to whatever Capybara.default_driver is, then if the `js` metadata exists it sets the driver to the value of Capybara.javascript_driver, and then if `driver` metadata exists it sets it to that - ie.  `driver` metadata takes priority over 'js' and if nothing you just get default_driver.  What this means is without any extra additions you could just specify `driver: :webkit_billy` on a test and get :webkit_billy used for that test.

To add your desired behavior of being able to specify `billy: true` you just need

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, billy: true) do
    Capybara.current_driver     = :webkit_billy
  end
end
```

somewhere after you've required 'capybara/rspec' but before your database cleaner configuration is defined.  Then set Capybara.default_driver to whatever driver you want to use when no metadata is specified, and Capybara.javascript_driver to whatever driver you want to use when `js` metadata is specified.  So - if you wanted to always use the :webkit driver (other than when billy is specified) set `Capybara.default_driver = :webkit` and you never need to specify `js: true` , but can always make specific tests use rack_test by adding `driver: :rack_test` metadata to a specific test.

Note: This supposes you are using the recommended database_cleaner config - https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example - which changes database strategy based on the actual driver being used and not just based on the presence of the `js` metadata.

Answer (score 0):

how about you try this:

```
config.before(:each, billy: true) do |example|
      Capybara.current_driver     = :webkit_billy
      Capybara.javascript_driver  = :webkit_billy
end
```

or to go your current approach, you'd do:

```
config.before(:each) do |example|
    if example.metadata[:billy] # this should either be true or nil
      Capybara.current_driver     = :webkit_billy
      Capybara.javascript_driver  = :webkit_billy
    else
      Capybara.current_driver     = :webkit
      Capybara.javascript_driver  = :webkit 
    end
  end
```